# Perform analysis for files in all subdirectories and save output in each subdirectory?

Tags: bash, vcf-variant-call-format

In a parent directory, I have several sub-directories, each of them contain one .vcf.gz file on which analysis should be performed. I want to run following commands on all .vcf.gz files in all subdirectories. I tried with the folowing code, but **the result file is not saved in the corresponding subdirectory**. It is saved in main directory, and every time it got overwritten with next one.

```
    find . -type f -name '*.vcf'      \

   -exec vcftools --gzvcf {} --minGQ 20 --recode --out GENO_FILT_GQ20 ';'   \

   -exec vcftools --vcf GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf --max-missing 0.7 --out filtered  ';'\

   -exec vcftools --vcf GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf --min-alleles 2 --max-alleles 2  ';'\

   -exec /home/bioinformatics/Dokumente/pipeline_test/annovar/convert2annovar.pl \
    -format vcf4 GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf \
    -outfile ALL_genepy.input \
    -allsample \
    -withfreq \
    -include 2>annovar.log ';'\

   -exec /home/bioinformatics/Dokumente/pipeline_test/annovar/table_annovar.pl \
        ALL_genepy.input \
        /home/bioinformatics/Dokumente/pipeline_test/annovar/humandb/ \
        -buildver hg19 \
        -out ALL_genepy \
        -remove \
        -protocol refGene,gnomad_exome,cadd13,eigen,revel,gwava,dann \
        -operation g,f,f,f,f,f,f \
        --thread 40 \
        --maxgenethread 40 \
        -nastring . >>annovar.log';'\

    -exec cut -f 18- ALL_genepy.input > a1';'\

    -exec zgrep '^#CHR' GENO_FILT_GQ20.recode.vcf | cut -f 10- > b1';'\

    -exec cat b1 a1 > ALL_temp';'\

    -exec paste ALL_genepy.hg19_multianno.txt ALL_temp > ALL_genepy.meta';'\

    -exec rm a1 b1 ALL_temp #remove';'\

    -exec mkdir CADD13_RawScore Eigen GWAVA_region_score GWAVA_tss_score dann REVEL ';'\

    -exec grep "^Chr" ALL_genepy.meta> header ';'\

    -exec chmod +x GENEPY_1.2.sh ';'\

    -exec while read gene; do

  sh GENEPY_1.2.sh $gene
done < gene.list ';'\
done
```

Comment: That is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` runs the command, it's not "syntax aware" and is not special. If you write:

```
find blabla -exec blabla 2>something ';' -exec blabla >something ';'
```

The redirections are parsed by the shell **not** by `find`. It's the same as:

```
find blabla -exec blabla ';' -exec blabla  ';' 2>something >something
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - redirections
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - the command with argumnets
```

Ditch all the `exec` and just do a while loop:

```
find blabla |
while IFS= read -r f; do
    : use "$f" here
done
```

Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net